# Why my options menu changes to ActionBar overflow menu unexpectedly?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I use in my `MainActivity` simple Option Menu. by click on the menu's first Item can go to `SecondActivity` that I use following code for converting this Activity's menu to ActionBar Overflow menu for devices with menu button :

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuey = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuey != null) {
            menuey.setAccessible(true);
            menuey.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {}
```

but sometimes( that I don't know exactly) when I back to `MainActivity` , the MainActivity's simple Option Menu changes to actionBar overflow menu with those three dots

tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code and solve it but if you have more simple code answer please:

```
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuey = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if (menuey != null) {
            menuey.setAccessible(true);
            menuey.setBoolean(config, true);
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e) {}
}
```